# Accessing column data by name with lsqlite3 db_rows?

Tags: lua

I'm using the `lsqlite3` library to retrieve data from a sqlite database.  When I use the `db:rows` function I am able to access data with an integer index, but it would be more convenient if I could access by name.

Currently I'm doing something like this.

```
sql=[=[
  SELECT max([index]) as last FROM migrations
]=]

for a in db:rows(sql) do 
  print(a[1])
end
```

Here I have accessed `last` using a[1], but I would like to do something like `a.last` or `a["last"]` to access this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
for a in db:nrows(sql) do 
  print(a.last)
end
```